# delete all edges with 0 jaccard similarity

Tags: r, igraph

I don't know anything about R language(syntax)

How can I delete all edges with *weight=0* from the graph?
 For example all edges with 0 similarity [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1LTV.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's best practice to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250). In addition, it's not clear what exactly you're looking for: _weight_ is commonly associated with edge weights. However, `similarity` compares vertices.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example on how to delete edges between vertices with zero jaccard similarity:

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_ring(5) + edges(4,1,2,2)  
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(g)
(s <- similarity(g, method = "jaccard"))
idx <- which(s == 0, arr.ind = T)
g2 <- g - edges(as.vector(t(idx)))
plot(g2)
```

Comment: thank you. I am looking for that convert a unique connected graph to a jungle (by delete all edges with weight=0) 
then compute "edge.betweenness.community()" for each component Simultaneously(parallel computing)

is it possible by R?

Comment: @SaeedVA You should prly provide an example in the veins I did. "unique connected graph", "jungle", ... many open questions. just follow the links in the comments and put together example code in a new question, which can be run by anyone